# Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED, 'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11)

Tags: java, android, react-native, gradle, java-11

```
info Running jetifier to migrate libraries to AndroidX. You can disable it using "--no-jetifier" flag.
Jetifier found 936 file(s) to forward-jetify. Using 12 workers...
info JS server already running.
info Installing the app...

> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.
1 actionable task: 1 executed

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
   > Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

error Failed to install the app. Make sure you have the Android development environment set up: https://reactnative.dev/docs/environment-setup.
Error: Command failed: gradlew.bat app:installDebug -PreactNativeDevServerPort=8081

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
   > Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s

    at makeError (C:\Users\dhanp\React native projects\test3\ProjectName\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at C:\Users\dhanp\React native projects\test3\ProjectName\node_modules\execa\index.js:278:16
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async runOnAllDevices (C:\Users\dhanp\React native projects\test3\ProjectName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\build\commands\runAndroid\runOnAllDevices.js:109:5)
    at async Command.handleAction (C:\Users\dhanp\React native projects\test3\ProjectName\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli\build\index.js:192:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details
```

I have seen solutions which involve changing the classpath() and distribution URL, but I have already done it.

from my build.gradle file:

```
dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
        classpath("de.undercouch:gradle-download-task:4.1.2")
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
```

from gradle-wrapper

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.4.2-all.zip
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
```

None of this fixes the error, additionally, i have noticed that running gradlew clean also provokes the same error

```
> Task :react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin FAILED
'compileJava' task (current target is 1.8) and 'compileKotlin' task (current target is 11) jvm target compatibility should be set to the same Java version.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin'.
> Failed to query the value of task ':react-native-gradle-plugin:compileKotlin' property 'compilerRunner$kotlin_gradle_plugin'.
   > Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation. Make sure Kotlin compilation is running on a JDK, not JRE.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 4s
1 actionable task: 1 executed
```

I have also tried adding the following piece of code to the build.gradle file

```
android {
compileOptions {
sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
}

kotlinOptions {
jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_11.toString()
}
}
```

kindly help me fix this, I used to use EXPO CLI previously and everything was working well, All of this happened in an attempt to learn the React-native CLI.

Comment: Simply you need to install kotlin on Android Studio and do Gradle Sync again.

Answer (score 17):

I had the same problem and to solve this problem I changed in gradle-wrapper.properties file

before:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.3.3-all.zip
```

after:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
```

Comment: This only applies to react-native 0.70+

Comment: This fixed it for me when upgrading to Expo 48. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I changed gradle version and solved it.
[Reference](https://bocoder.tistory.com/125)

```
//before
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.9-bin.zip

//after
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5.1-all.zip
```

Answer (score 2):

I am facing the same issue where All Java packages were installed or synced perfectly but kotlin packages were not synced it throws an error of kotlin compilation.

I install kotlin package on Android Studio by following [This](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/install-eap-plugin.html).

> Android Studio → Preferences… →Plugins → Browse Repository → type “Kotlin” in search box → install

After that, you need to remove the cache of this project from

> File -> Invalidate caches -> Invalidate and Restart.

After that when your project is re-open and synced successfully then clean your project from `Build -> Clean Project`.

After that, all packages of kotlin were installed perfectly.

Comment: Hi thank you for the response, but I already have kotlin plugin installed. Also when I open the project on android studio, I'm unable to gradle sync it. Isn't the issue related to changing the java version from 1.8 to 11?

Answer (score 1):

I just installed jdk11 then run cd ./android/ && ./gradlew clean That works for me

We have to take care **Gradle compatibility version with java version** for react-native or flutter both framework. You can take a look for checking compatible version in mentioned url
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/compatibility.html

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same issue using expo

I removed the `eas.json` file, as `eas build` creates a new `eas.json` file

It worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and to solve this problem I did:

1. Installed java 11 and uninstalled that java 8;
2. In `package.json` I prefixed the version with `^`, then `yarn install`. *(Update `react native` version `0.68.2` for `^0.68.2`)*

Reference: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/34410

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me when I had the same issues:

```
rm -rf ./node_modules
yarn
npm run android
```

Deleted the node_modules and reinstalled. I think the issue could also be because I had used Android Studio to install the Gradle.
Also check incase you have multiple versions of Java JDK installed, check to be sure of which one is being used by React Native.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in react-native project and to solve this problem I comment this org.gradle.java.home=/Library/Java/..., in gradle.properties file.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wdxm6.png

goto android folder and run

- ./gradlew clean
- ./gradlew build

back to folder project run

- npx react-native run-android

node v14.21.3 (npm v6.14.18),
react: 17.0.2,
react-native: 0.68.2,
jdk-17,
gradle-7.4-all.zip

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by running [expo-doctor](https://www.npmjs.com/package/expo-doctor):

```
npx expo-doctor
```

and install it then it adjust the dependencies according to your sdk version, this solved my error

Answer (score -1):

info Opening app on Android...
info A dev server is already running for this project on port 8081.
info Installing the app...

> Task :gradle-plugin:compileKotlin UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:compileJava NO-SOURCE
> Task :gradle-plugin:pluginDescriptors UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:processResources UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:classes UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:jar UP-TO-DATE
> Task :gradle-plugin:inspectClassesForKotlinIC UP-TO-DATE

> Configure project :react-native-reanimated
> Android gradle plugin: 8.1.1
> Gradle: 8.3
> Observed package id 'platforms;android-33' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\zahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33-3' (Expected 'C:\Users\zahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33')
> Warning: Observed package id 'platforms;android-33' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\zahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33-3' (Expected 'C:\Users\zahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33')
> Warning: Observed package id 'platforms;android-33' in inconsistent location 'C:\Users\zahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33-3' (Expected 'C:\Users\zahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platforms\android-33')
> Checking the license for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 in C:\Users\zahid\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\licenses
> License for package NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 accepted.
> Preparing "Install NDK (Side by side) 25.1.8937393 v.25.1.8937393".

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -4):

Found the solution, not sure why it works though

i used the following commands to start the build

```
npm start
```

now open another terminal and execute the following

```
npm run android
```

**instead of**

```
npx react-native start
```

and

```
npx react-native run-android
```

where the latter is suggested by the official documentation

Comment: it even not related to question, it just a command to run react native app